# BackgroundWorker RunWorkerAsync fails after ugrade to .net 4.5. Async issue

Tags: .net, backgroundworker, .net-4.5, async-await

folks, friends........I need backup. I had a perfectly functional bulk mailing system before upgrading my .Net framework to 4.5. This is what i get when i try to run my background worker async

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %> method.

Every Async call fails including my send mail async action method

```
mailSmtpClient.SendAsync(mailMessage, userState);
```

i have tried concepts such as changing my webconfig to look like this:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have also tried

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bw.RunWorkerAsync());
```

When i try the second, it flushed my HttpContext and get a HttpContext exception

My code is a basic background worker

```
public void startsending() {

   //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bw.RunWorkerAsync()); fails
   bw.RunWorkerAsync();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();  // send all buffered output to client
   HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: MVC or WebPages? What calls `startsending`? Why are you using a background worker?

Comment: I was using background worker because it was an existing code from my previous .NET 4.0 configuration. I guess BW wass completely crucified in 4.5. I had to rewrite the whole class with .net 4.5 async/await functionality. it actually worked better with less pain.

Answer (score 0):

The setting aspnet:AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages defaults to false. Try setting it to true.